# How to create index entry for \n?

Tags: indexing

I can't get LaTeX to generate index entry for newline `\n`. I tried `\index{"\\n"}` and `\index{"\n"}` and `\index{\n}` and `\index{\\n}`. None of these seem to work.

I am getting errors like:

```
! LaTeX Error: There's no line here to end.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.14   \item \\n
                |hyperpage, 19
```

Anyone knows?

Comment: I am struggling to understand why you would need this.

Answer (score 9):

If you want it alphabetized under symbols use

```
\index{\n@\texttt{\string\n}}
```

If you want it alphabetized under "n", use

```
\index{n@\texttt{\string\n}}
```