# index entries for exactly !( and !)

Tags: indexing

I did look at [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/19735/42406) answer to a similar question. It is about my [bismon](https://github.com/bstarynk/bismon/) GPLv3+ free software project on `github`  ([commit `b08143a1478f`](https://github.com/bstarynk/bismon/commit/b08143a1478f36230e7fc86409ed19d5cd801f13) if that matters) whose LaTeX-ed documentation (partly generated) is under its [`doc/` sub-directory](https://github.com/bstarynk/bismon/tree/master/doc). My computer is running on Linux/Debian/Sid, and its LaTeX subsystem is `texlive-full   2018.20190227`.

For [this draft report](https://starynkevitch.net/Basile/bismon-chariot-doc.pdf/) (in PDF, its §2.3.2 near figure 4 page 34) obtained with `pdflatex`, called from my [`build-bismon-doc.sh`](https://github.com/bstarynk/bismon/blob/master/build-bismon-doc.sh) shell script, invoked by `make latexdoc`) obtained from LaTeX source files (under `doc/` ) **I need to have an index entry for the *exact* strings `!(` and `!)`**, preferably formatted in a fixed-width teletype looking font (so using `\texttt` in LaTeX parlance). This is [in file `doc/datapersist-bm.tex` around line 640](https://github.com/bstarynk/bismon/blob/master/doc/datapersist-bm.tex#L640) where the current (not yet `git commit`-ed, of course) LaTeX code has:

```
\begin{quote}
\begin{small}

  The lines starting with \texttt{«} or \texttt{!(}
  \index{{!(}@\texttt{!(}} \index{«@\texttt{«}}
  and with \texttt{»} or \texttt{!)}
  \index{{!)}@\texttt{!(}} \index{»@\texttt{»}}
  are delimiting the object's persistent
  representation. Comments~\footnote{Once the persistence code -
    loading and dumping of the state - is mature enough, we will
    disable generation of comments in data files.} can start with a
  bar \texttt{|} till the following bar, or with two slashes
  \texttt{//} till the end of line.  {\verb+!~+} with matching
         {\verb+(~+} ... \verb+~)+ are for ``modifications'' (here, we
         set the \index{name}{\texttt{name}} of that object to
         \texttt{first\_test\_module}). Object payloads are also
         dumped in such ``modification'' form. \verb+!@+ puts the
         \index{mtime}{\emph{mtime}}. \verb+!$+ \textit{classobjid}
         sets the \index{class}{class} to the object of objid
         \textit{classobjid}. \verb+!:+ \textit{attrobj}
         \textit{valattr} put the attribute \textit{attrobj}
         associated with the value \textit{valattr}. \verb+!#+
         \textit{nbcomp} reserve the spaces for \textit{nbcomp}, and
         \verb/!&/~\textit{valcomp} appends the value \textit{valcomp}
         as a component.

%% next paragraph was removed for brevity on this LaTeX forum question
\end{small}
\end{quote}
```

What am I doing wrongly above?

And  the suggested `\index{"!"(@\texttt{!(}}` does not work!

Comment: Did you try `\index{"!"(@\texttt{!(}}`?

Comment: Thanks, but it does not work...

Comment: Start my making a full (but minimal) example we can copy and test as is. Additionally, exactly which indexing programme are you using?

Comment: @greg I cannot get that to work either, but `\index{"!"(@\texttt{"!(}}` does work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to quote the `!`, which is a special character for MakeIndex, both before and after `@`.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{imakeidx}

\makeindex

\begin{document}

\begin{quote}\small
The lines starting with \index{«@\texttt{«}}\texttt{«} or \index{"!(@\texttt{"!(}}\texttt{!(}
and with \index{»@\texttt{»}}\texttt{»} or \index{"!)@\texttt{"!(}}\texttt{!)}
are delimiting the object's persistent representation. 
Comments~\footnote{Once the persistence code---loading and dumping of the state---is mature 
enough, we will disable generation of comments in data files.} can start with a 
bar~\texttt{|} till the following bar, or with two slashes~\texttt{//} till the 
end of line.  
%
\verb+!~+ with matching \verb+(~+ ... \verb+~)+ are for ``modifications'' (here, we
set the \index{name}{\texttt{name}} of that object to \texttt{first\_test\_module}). 
Object payloads are also dumped in such ``modification'' form.
%
\verb+!@+ puts the \index{mtime}{\emph{mtime}}.
%
\verb+!$+ \textit{classobjid} sets the \index{class}{class} to the object of 
objid \textit{classobjid}.
%
\verb+!:+ \textit{attrobj} \textit{valattr} put the attribute \textit{attrobj}
associated with the value \textit{valattr}.
%
\verb+!#+ \textit{nbcomp} reserve the spaces for \textit{nbcomp}, and
%
\verb/!&/~\textit{valcomp} appends the value \textit{valcomp} as a component.
\end{quote}

\printindex

\end{document}
```

Here's the produced `.ind` file:

```latex
\begin{theindex}

  \item \texttt{!(}, 1
  \item \texttt{!(}, 1
  \item \texttt{\IeC {\guillemotleft }}, 1
  \item \texttt{\IeC {\guillemotright }}, 1

  \indexspace

  \item class, 1

  \indexspace

  \item mtime, 1

  \indexspace

  \item name, 1

\end{theindex}
```

Comment: Thanks a big lot. That worked.

Comment: Could you explain a bit more what exactly `You need to quote the !`  means. I don't know how in general should I quote something in LaTeX. I do know the role of `quote` or of `'` in Scheme or Lisp (and the role of `'`  in C)

Comment: Concretely, I also need to index `!|`  and `Σ` and I cannot adapt your answer. A general short explanation (or just some URL) about quotation in LaTeX is welcome. I only vaguely know about catcodes

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch MakeIndex doesn't know Unicode/UTF-8 (as you see from `«`). The quote character for it is `"` and means “treat the following special character literally”.

Comment: So `"` is quoting a single byte, or potentially a single multi-byte UTF-8 character?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch No, as I said MakeIndex knows nothing about UTF-8

Comment: So you mean that `"` for MakeIndex means treat the next *byte* literally?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Yes, that's all you can do. Sorting characters such as `«` or `Σ` will be problematic. You may consider Xindy.